# Custom page is not displayng when user mistyped url

Tags: asp.net

I have a below code in my web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>    
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
    <remove statusCode="404"/>
    <remove statusCode="500"/>
    <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL"
    path="~/ERRORPAGES/Pagenotfound.aspx"/>
    <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL"
    path="~/ERRORPAGES/Pagenotfound.aspx"/>
  </httpErrors> </system.webServer>
```

I have Pagenotfound.aspx page which is called when user mistyped url unfortunately it is not calling instead i am getting error like 
The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Please suggest me how to do? i am testing it from my development machine running through visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you might need [custom error messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/ERRORPAGES/GenericError.aspx" mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ERRORPAGES/Pagenotfound.aspx"/>
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/ERRORPAGES/Pagenotfound.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

> [The customErrors element] provides information about custom error
>   messages for an ASP.NET application. The customErrors element can be
>   defined at any level in the application file hierarchy.

Keep in mind that the `mode` attribute of the `customErrors` tag is required. Here are the options for it:

> On - Specifies that custom errors are enabled. If no defaultRedirect
>   attribute is specified, users see a generic error. The custom errors
>   are shown to the remote clients and to the local host.
>
> Off - Specifies that custom errors are disabled. The detailed ASP.NET
>   errors are shown to the remote clients and to the local host.
>
> RemoteOnly - Specifies that custom errors are shown only to the remote
>   clients, and that ASP.NET errors are shown to the local host. This is
>   the default value.

All block quotes are from the linked article from MSDN.

Comment: getting below error after updating to above
Server Error in '/Website' Application.
 An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on the local server machine, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly".

Comment: Did you copy the entire block of code? In your case you should already have the `<configuration><system.web></system.web></configuration>` section available so you would only need to copy the `<customErrors></customErrors>` block along with everything in it and place that inside of your existing `<system.web>` block.